# How can i use map on FileList array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron

can i use `map` on `FileList`? the object is iterable so maybe there's some way to make it work with `map`?

for example:

```js
    window.addEventListener('drop', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if(e.dataTransfer?.files) {
        const files = e.dataTransfer.files.map(f => f.path); // imaginary code
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.map()` exists only on `Array.prototype`, not on [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList). But you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert any iterable object into an array, and then use the map function:

```
const files = Array.from(e.dataTransfer.files).map(f => f.path);
```

Comment: didn't know about `Array.from()` but that's what I was looking for after all :)